# What is this funky "window cleaning" sound referred to as?

Tags: instruments, synthesizer, pop-music

Example of it in the opening of Persona 4 Dancing All Night's Opening

https://www.youtube.com/embed/ddXM6HX1PgU?start=30&end=45 (from 0:30 to 0:45)

Another somewhat example might be the Goron City theme from Ocarina of Time.

What is this funky window-wiping sound effect referred to as? And are there any other prominent examples?

Answer (score 6):

The Zelda example seems to be emulating the samba instrument [cuica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cu%C3%ADca). The first example is less clear, since it’s a series of discrete notes, but it might be inspired by the same source.